# How can I link a CarouselView and Indicator when using C# markup in my Xamarin forms app?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is the XAML Code from the documentation:

```
<StackLayout>
    <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                  IndicatorView="indicatorView">
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <!-- DataTemplate that defines item appearance -->
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
    <IndicatorView x:Name="indicatorView"/>
</StackLayout>
```

I am using C# Markup so my code looks like this (styling code and some layout settings removed to keep simple for SO question):

```
CarouselView ScrollingImageView() => new CarouselView
{
   ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
   {})
}
.Bind(ItemsView.ItemsSourceProperty, nameof(_vm.ListOfItems))
.Bind(CarouselView.PositionProperty, nameof(_vm.ScrollingImageViewerPosition));

IndicatorView IndicatorView() => new IndicatorView
{
    IndicatorsShape = IndicatorShape.Circle,
};


Grid ButtonIndicatorGrid() => new Grid
{
    Children = { IndicatorView().Row(0).Column(1) }
};

void Build() => Content =
new Grid
{ 
   Children = {
       ScrollingImageView().Row(0),
       ButtonIndicatorGrid().Row(1),
   }
};
```

> In this example, the IndicatorView is rendered beneath the
> CarouselView, with an indicator for each item in the CarouselView. The
> IndicatorView is populated with data by setting the
> CarouselView.IndicatorView property to the IndicatorView object. Each
> indicator is a light gray circle, while the indicator that represents
> the current item in the CarouselView is dark gray.  Setting the
> CarouselView.IndicatorView property results in the
> IndicatorView.Position property binding to the CarouselView.Position
> property, and the IndicatorView.ItemsSource property binding to the
> CarouselView.ItemsSource property.

Now I cannot find an example of how to do this with C#.  In XAML it works by setting the name but how can I do the same thing in C# as from what I understand (please correct me if wrong), I cannot set the name in C# in the same way as in XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to maintain a reference to your UI objects when you create them

```
var iv = IndicatorView();
var cv = ScrollingImageView();

cv.IndicatorView = iv;
```

Comment: Thanks,  do you have an idea how I could fit that into the way I am creating my page with the call to Build() =>.  I'm just a bit unclear. Do you suggest creating CarouselView _cv; as a field and doing _cv = ScrollingImageView(); before Build(), and then in Build using _cv..Row(0) ?    I'm also wondering if I could do it by detecting when the carousel position changed and then binding that to the position of the indicator.  Do you think that idea would also work?

Comment: do it however you want.  There is nothing that prevents you from using the Fluent approach and also maintaining references to objects as you create them